# Move up and down in block increments in VSCode - Keybinding?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I find myself navigating through my code with `Arrow-up` and `Arrow-down` a lot. This is quite slow. I'd love to be able to move my cursor not line by line but maybe in increments of blocks. Is there a shortcut for this?

I feel this question is too simple to not have an answer yet. If it does, feel free to mark it as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by#select-by-line-number)

You give an expression on where you want the cursor to be

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+k",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "selectby.lineNr",
    "args": { "lineNrEx": "c-n==10" }
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+j",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "selectby.lineNr",
    "args": { "lineNrEx": "n-c==10" }
  }
```

To move the cursor 10 lines at a time

You can choose any key binding.